# How to permanently heighten and widen Paint's text box?

Tags: microsoft-paint

Pls see two GIFs underneath. The text box is too small - 99% of the time, I type way more text. I don't want to drag arrows every time I start new text box.

**Paint 3D**
[image]
**Paint**

[image]

Comment: MS paint is not discontinued

Answer (score 2):

Instead of clicking only one time, press down your left mouse button then drag and make as big a box as you would feel you will require and then release the mouse button.

This way you can every time make a custom-size box as you need.

It's exactly this way for Paint 3D as well.

Comment: @Pamela lee , Please click on the tick mark if my answer has solved your issue.

Comment: how does this answer my question? "This way you can every time" - I don't want to do this EVERY TIME.

Comment: @PamelaLee I very much doubt there's a setting for this.  Click and drag is likely as good as you'll get.

Comment: @PamelaLee  I understand this doesn't do what you want, but there is no such option to make the default text box bigger and click and drag is the next best alternative.
Just trying to help in making your work easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I ran into a similar issue. What helped was resizing the zoom-in by zooming out. (with CTRL + mouse scroll down) This lead to a resized text field as well. The issue I had was that I zoomed in far too much while using very large font trying to fit the text neatly. But the text-field scales proportional to the zoom-in so it was too small. Zooming out solved the issue for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Type all the text you need to, press enter when finished. The text box should automatically resize to fit the text you've entered, but if some of your text is outside the text box, grab the text box by any of the corners and drag until it all fits.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer already given?

Comment: Just pointing out that you don't need to alter the text box size at all. The text box resizes automatically to accommodate the text you enter, even if you change the text size. Hope this answers your rather condescending question.

Comment: Adding "...the text box size should automatically resize to fit the entered text, but if it doesn't..." to the answer should differentiate your answer better and make your answer probably better than the current answer, which is a good way to get upvotes in appreciation.

Comment: I'm not looking for upvotes in appreciation, so let's just leave it at that. Thanks.

Comment: Everyone has a different carrot, but a general goal of this site is that questions and answers be complete, having sufficient information to make them self-contained and clear in themselves. You don't have to be "looking for upvotes" for that to apply to you too.